# x86 Assembly Stack Reservation

Tags: x86

Consider this simple C program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the corresponding 32 bit assembly as compiled by gcc

```
    .file   "a.c"
        .section        .rodata
    .LC0:
        .string "Hello World"
        .text
    .globl func
        .type   func, @function
    func:
         pushl   %ebp
         movl    %esp, %ebp
         subl    $24, %esp
         movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
         call    puts
         movl    $0, %eax
         leave
         ret
         .size   func, .-func
    .globl main
         .type   main, @function
    main:
          pushl   %ebp
          movl    %esp, %ebp
          andl    $-16, %esp
          subl    $16, %esp
          movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
          call    puts
          movl    $0, %eax
          leave
          ret
          .size   main, .-main
          .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
          .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Why does gcc reserve 24 bytes for the string "Hello World" in the function 'func()' but only 16 bytes in the main function for the same string ?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the string, it never gets loaded on the stack.  The $16 in the main function prologue is there to get the stack pointer aligned.  Note the andl instruction.

Comment: Hans, you are talking about the andl instruction in main. Its the andl instruction that aligns the stack pointer to the page boundary. I am asking about the subl $16, (%esp) in the main function & subl $24, (%esp) in func

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is trying to allocate 16B for both functions (it's questionable whether it needs that much).

In "main", it simply allocates 16B and calls puts. Note that the stack is aligned to 0 mod 16 before the call, because this is required in the ABI (that is, your stack much always be 0 mod 16 BEFORE a call).

In func, the stack comes in 12 mod 16 aligned (due to the return address). We then push ebp, making it 8 mod 16. Now, we want to allocate 16B on the stack (similar to main), but we also want the stack to be 0 mod 16 byte aligned before the call to put, therefore, we need to subtract 8 + 16 bytes, which is 24.